# Does the idempotent law for union of a set imply that the measure of a set is zero?!!!

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Sorry in advance for this question!!!

The idempotent law for union of a set is :

A= A $\cup$ A

But it seems to imply that for the measure we get:

m(A)=m(A)+m(A)=2$\cdot$m(A),

which, then would imply that

m(A)=$0$

And so,the measure of every set would be zero!!!!
What I am doing wrong????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have that ${\frak m}A = 2\,{\frak m}A$ if the union $A = A \cup A$ were **disjoint**. This is not the case, unless $A = \varnothing$ (and here $0 = 2 \cdot 0$ is ok).

Comment: Paaah... Thank you very much, I saw that Kolmogorov used this argument to show that the measure of the empty set was zero, and it seemed to generalized for an arbitrary set, but your argument is completely valid and clear... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We don't assume that $ m( A \cup B ) = m(A) + m(B) $ for *every* pair of sets $A, B$, but only for when they're disjoint. Refer to a simple example of a measure like Lebesgue measure on the real line, i.e. "length". We expect to be able to add the lengths of two segments when they don't touch (or only touch in small ways), but if I have two segments that overlap significantly, I won't add their lengths together because I'll be "double-counting" some of it.